# BLL Return String Or DTO

Tags: c#, oop, exception, design-patterns

I'm confused how to return the result from the business layer. Sometimes I need to return the message if it does not pass the criteria. For example:

```
public SalesDTO GetSalesByPrescriptionNo(string prescriptionNo)
{
    int count = unitOfWork.SalesRepository.GetNumberOfPrescriptionUsed(prescriptionNo);
    if (count > 5)
        // I cannot return string/error information 
        // since the function is return SalesDTO type
        return "Cannot used anymore";
        
    var sales = unitOfWork.SalesRepository.GetSalesByPrescriptionNo(prescriptionNo);
    var salesDTO = Mapper.MapToDTO(sales);
    return salesDTO;
}
```

Based on the good OOP/OOD implementation, how should I handle the multiple result from the BLL?

Comment: @IlyaChumakov it's not an error, why it should be treated as an exception? it's a good oop approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an exceptional case when the method cannot deliver the expected result.

The caller have either not validated the information used when calling the method, or trying to fetch something that simply do not exist.

If you use a return value to indicate that, you will always have to deal with two different execution paths for every method call. The code gets much more cluttered then.

Exceptions on the other hand will automatically travel back through all method invocations until it comes to a try/catch statement. Hence no need to check for exceptions unless you really can handle it.

> it's not an error, why it should be treated as an exception? it's a good oop approach?

It ***is*** an exception. The method `GetSalesByPrescriptionNo` indicates that it will deliver the sales. It's nothing in the name, the contract, that indicates that it may not be able to return sales in some situations. Hence the caller **expect** the method to succeed.

Either name the method `TryGetSalesByPrescriptionNo` or throw an exception.

If you choose the exception path you typically have another method somewhere which can check if it's OK to invoke other methods on that prescription. (i.e. your counter check)

You can do something like:

```
if (IsPrescriptionActive(prescriptionNo))
{
    var sales = GetSalesByPrescriptionNo(prescriptionNo);
    //do something with sales
}
```

imho I like that better than:

```
if (!TryGetSalesByPrescriptionNo(prescriptionNo, out sales))
{
    //do something with sales
}
```

because you can't understand by looking at the call why the method fails. That you can with the first alternative.

However, If you expect that the user have entered a valid prescription number (which is still active) there is no reason to use an extra check. Simply use:

```
var sales = GetSalesByPrescriptionNo(prescriptionNo);
//do something with sales
```

As it's really an exceptional case in that situation. i.e. if you use `IsPrescriptionActive` you are hiding a bug (as the valid subscription got invalid somewhere on the road).

**Summary**

1. The prescription should be validated in the UI and reported directly to the user.
2. If an invalid prescription is found in the business layer, throw an exception.

Comment: I see, I agree about "The code gets much more cluttered then" thank you for the great explanation. I don't get it "you typically have another method somewhere" could you give an example?